# std::vector of structs which require a constructor

Tags: c++

The problem only appears when adding the `~MyClass()` function. I think the error is undefined behaviour or has something to do with the `const MyClass&` maybe this kind reference doesn't work with `emplace_back`.
Comments explain the rest:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct MyClass
{
    const int x;

    MyClass(int _x) : x(_x)
    {
    }
};

struct MyClass2
{
    std::unique_ptr<MyClass> my;

    MyClass2(const MyClass& my2)
    {
        my.reset(new MyClass(my2.x));
    }
    
    // when adding this function
    // error: static assertion failed: result type must be constructible from input type
    ~MyClass2()
    {
        printf("deleting\n");
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyClass main(12);

    std::vector<MyClass2> ts;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        ts.emplace_back(main);
    }

    printf("%i\n", ts[0].my->x);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Haven't tested it but surely it should be `printf("%i\n", *(ts[0].x));` You need to dereference the smart pointer to get the integer.

Comment: `*x.get() = y;` can be replaced with `*x = y;`, no need for `get()`.

Comment: There's a close button above. And when it's closed there's a delete button.

Comment: OK, I guess that's because you are the author. Press it if you want the post deleted.

Comment: @deanqx Only higher reputation users see the "close" button. But you can use "delete". It will make the question invisible to most users. You can later "undelete" it if you e.g. have edited it.

Comment: Adding a destructor removes the implicit move constructor (and assignment operator) that you need for the `std::unique_ptr` member. You can add them back in as `MyClass2(MyClass2&&) = default; MyClass2& operator=(MyClass2&&) = default;`

Comment: That's bad cause `int x` is actually `const`

Answer (score 0):

You need to dereference the `std::unique_ptr` in order to access the data.

```cpp
int main()
{
    std::vector<MyClass> ts;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        ts.emplace_back(123);
    }

    // error: use of deleted function 'std::unique_ptr'
    printf("%i\n", *ts[0].x);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: that was a typo from copying, fixed that now

Answer (score -1):

Calling the emplace_back function attempts to create a new MyClass2 object and copy that object into the vector. However, unique_ptr objects cannot be copied. Therefore, you need to write a copy constructor for MyClass2 like this

```
MyClass2(const MyClass2& my2)
{
    my.reset();
}
```

Comment: emplace moves, not copies

Comment: If this is true it could be fixed with a raw pointer but that would lead to bad code readability

Comment: Actually emplace functions not move. They are creates new object by using perfect forwarding. 

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace

Comment: I think shared_ptr is better option for this situation. Because shared_ptr can be copied.